# How to get distinct values using group_concat() in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-concat

I want all the distinct courier codes for that particular month,state and city in column with ',' as separator. I tried group_concat() but the codes are repeating.

**Sample table**

| Month | City | State | Pincode | Courier | Total_orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | City1 | State1 | 110021 | DTDC | 20000 |
| 1 | City1 | State1 | 110021 | GA | 30000 |
| 2 | City1 | State1 | 110021 | DTDC | 10000 |
| 1 | City2 | State2 | 110029 | DTDC | 25000 |
| 1 | City2 | State2 | 110029 | DTDC | 20000 |
| 1 | City2 | State2 | 110029 | DTDC | 15000 |

```
select distinct Pincode, Month, City, State, 
sum(Total_orders) as Total_orders, 
group_concat(Courier) as CourierType
from table1
group by Pincode, Month
```

Output:

| Month | City | State | Pincode | CourierType | Total_orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | City1 | State1 | 110021 | DTDC,GA | 50000 |
| 2 | City1 | State1 | 110021 | DTDC | 10000 |
| 1 | City2 | State2 | 110029 | DTDC,DTDC,DTDC | 60000 |

But is there any way I can get only distinct codes instead of 'DTDC,DTDC,DTDC'? For a huge data set,this column with repetitive courier types is getting messy.

Desired output:

| Month | City | State | Pincode | CourierType | Total_orders |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | City1 | State1 | 110021 | DTDC,GA | 50000 |
| 2 | City1 | State1 | 110021 | DTDC | 10000 |
| 1 | City2 | State2 | 110029 | DTDC | 60000 |

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want `group_concat(distinct)` with the right `group by` columns:

```
select Pincode, Month, City, State, 
       sum(Total_orders) as Total_orders, 
       group_concat(distinct Courier) as CourierType
from table1
group by Pincode, Month, City, State
```